# Can't remove QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mac, qgis-2.18

I'm trying to completely remove and reinstall QGIS on my system (Mac os 10.11.6). I follow the steps in the Kyngchaos and delete the existing application. But on reinstalling framework, components and program I still see old plugins from prior installation. I can't delete these which i what i want to do. As screenshot, they are there but i can't uninstall or reinstall as both boxes are greyed out. I've installed the latest Kyngchaos framwork and build 2.18.15. Please can someone advise where these are stored on my system so i can delte them.

[image]

EDIT by looking in the package contents and going to folder Plugins/qgis I can remove all but these which aren't in that folder. If i delete everything in the folder it causes QGIS to break and I have to reinstall;

[image]

Comment: Plugins are stored in user accessable directory. i don't know for Mac OS, but QGIS has a log window, where you should find the plugin path. Then  go there (file manager) and delete the folders containing the plugins. Each plugin has its own folder...

Comment: In mac it doesn't give the full path so you can't go to it

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html i found this doc about plugins and pathes, including MacOS. May be you lost permissions on these pathes?

Comment: Thank you, well in that folder there are no plugins but they still appear within QGIS..

Comment: Have added an edit can nearly remove all now

Comment: The remaining plugins are installed and needed by Qgis. So leave them.

Comment: Thank you, have just read this and seen that http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

AsAndreas Muller's answer, on mac plugins should be installed here /Users/username/.qgis2/python/plugins;

to find out more go to > http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_plugins.html

and

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins are installed by default so may not be from the old install, but from this new one.

- DB Manager
- Processing
- GDAL Tools

Are all examples of these. They are core components of QGIS so should not be deleted.